# An inequality concerning $\pi$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Given $x_0=0,x_1,\ldots,x_n>0,x_1+\ldots+x_n=1$.

We want to prove $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1+x_0+\cdots +x_{i-1}}\sqrt{x_i+\cdots +x_n}}<\frac{\pi}2$$

**My progress:**

Let $x_0+\cdots+x_i=\sin \alpha_i$

We have $0=\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\cdots<\alpha_n=\frac{\pi}2$

Then the inequality becomes $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sin \alpha_i-\sin \alpha_{i-1}}{\cos \alpha_{i-1}}<\frac{\pi}2$$

Then I don't know how to deal with this trigonometric inequality.

Comment: By IVT, $\frac{\sin\alpha_i - \sin\alpha_{i-1}}{\cos\alpha_{i-1}} = \frac{\cos\beta_i}{\cos\alpha_{i-1}}(\alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1})$ for some $\beta_i \in (\alpha_{i-1},\alpha_i)$. Since $\cos\theta$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, all the $\frac{\cos\beta_i}{\cos\alpha_{i-1}} < 1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 6):

Hint. Let $t_i=x_0+\cdots +x_{i-1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n+1$. Then show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{\sqrt{1+t_i}\sqrt{1-t_i}}=\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)<\int_0^1f(t)\,dt=[\arcsin(t)]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
where $f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$. Note that $f$ is strictly increasing in $[0,1)$.